# Why is d3.format putting a "y" after a 0 on format?

Tags: d3.js

When formatting numbers, I've noticed d3 puts a "y" after a 0, so the following code:

```
d3.format('s.2')(new Number(0));
```

returns:

```
0y
```

Is this expected behaviour? I'd file an issue on github but I wanted to double check I'm not doing something stupid first.

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NgVnV/

Comment: I guess it's technically correct since you're asking for a number with SI suffix. I would open an issue for this though. It works fine if you just format `i` instead of `new Number(i)`.